# missing ic_affirmation_foreground.xml for android developer tutorial

Tags: android

I'm trying to complete a codelab where I polish the UI on an affirmations app and it tells me to download the files ic_affirmation_foreground.xml and ic_affirmation_background.xml.

I can't find these files to save my life.  I've done multiple google searches.  I've searched the tutorial site.  I've looked in android studio and searched github.  The instructions don't show where to get the files.

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-affirmations-app-polish?hl=en&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fcodelabs.developers.google.com%2F%3Fcat%3Dandroid#2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end there is a link to a github repository.  You will not find the files there, at least under the file names above.  I ended up copying xml from the foreground file in the drawable folder and xml from the background file in drawable-v24.

Maybe there were copyright issues.....??

It was a real pain.  Maybe the xml files were in the images.zip but nothing in the codelab or in the readme indicates any of that.

https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-affirmations-app-solution